# Sharepoint File storage options

Tags: sharepoint

We are in the middle of planning a Sharepoint infrastructure to handle various tasks. One of the tasks will be storage/index of invoices. Ideally we would like to keep the files (pdfs) out of the Sharepoint database on our existing file stores, but there seems to be conflicting information about this.

I have read the stuff about using external blobs, but they need to be kept on the same server as the database.

Do any one know ifs its possible to hold the file outside the database? We are going to use Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RBS (Remote Blob Storage) for such files so that you do not overload your SQL DB. This would allow you to use lower cost storage for the large scanned docs/attchments and improve SQL performance. MS has a number of documents on using RBS This MS article will assist you. [Technet RBS info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx)

It is possible to store data ona  separate server Technet article indicates "

A remote RBS provider stores the BLOBs on a separate server. This is typically on a separate volume on the same network as the database server.

Because the BLOBs are not stored in the same Filegroup with the metadata, some SharePoint Server 2010 features — for example, backup and restore in Central Administration — cannot be used with remote RBS providers. The metadata and the BLOBs must be managed separately. For more information about what features can be used with the provider, contact the provider manufacturer."

See also this answer [ServerFault 360542](https://serverfault.com/questions/360542/many-huge-files-in-sharepoint-any-stubbing-or-shortcutting-software-exist/360549#360549)